# Create paging in HTML table

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc-4

I have Html code that generates a table that contains a lot of records.

Here is the code:

```
 @model IEnumerable<UserContact>
    @{
        ViewBag.Title = "Contacts:";
    }
    <h2>
        Contacts</h2>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayText("First Name")
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayText("First Name")
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayText("Email")
            </th>
            <th>
            </th>
        </tr>
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.CheckBox("misha", new { onclick = "this.form.submit();" })
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.firstName)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.lastName)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.email)
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    </table>
```

This code is contained in razor partial view page.

My question is how can I create paging in table that described above?

Comment: you can do paging with datatable.js easily...

Comment: Ex, im newer in web programming,so if you can show me some examples i will be appreciate.

Comment: @Michael, have a look at this http://www.datatables.net/examples/basic_init/zero_configuration.html

Comment: @Michael..try below answer if need more help then plz comment...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**As per your comment i m showing complete example of datatable here :**

Jquery and CSS References :-

Links :-

http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js

http://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.2/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js

http://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.2/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css

Your Partial View :-

```
@model IEnumerable<UserContact>
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Contacts:";
}
<h2>
    Contacts</h2>
<table id="mydatatable">
  <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayText("First Name")
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayText("First Name")
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayText("Email")
        </th>
        <th>
        </th>
    </tr>
  <thead>

    <tbody>
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.CheckBox("misha", new { onclick = "this.form.submit();" })
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.firstName)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.lastName)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.email)
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
   <tbody>
</table>

<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#mydatatable').dataTable();
    });
</script>
```

**Last but not the least don't forget to add references of required jquery files on your page.**

Comment: I try the example but it dosent work for me, I add this reference jquery library:

<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

Comment: yes I get this error:
TypeError: $(...).dataTable is not a function
 

$('#mydatatable').dataTable();

Comment: @Michael...yes just include js file of datatable on your page..second link which i have given in my answer

Comment: @Ex, thanks for help.But I think that I found the problem.In my razor view page I have this row: Layout = "path to _Layout.cshtml page", when I change the row above to this row: Layout = Null, everything works perfectly when change the row back Layout = "path to _Layout.cshtml, it's not working.Do you have any idea what may caue to this problem? ;

Comment: yes in partial views there is no need to include layout just remove layout or put Layout=null..@Michael

Comment: @Ex, what if I want to use the code in not partial page and I want to use the layout page?

Comment: @Michael...then also it works fine .. if you are finding some difficulty then post a question with some code because without seeing code i can't help properly...thanks..

Answer (score 1):

```
 //cdn.datatables.net/1.10.2/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css
//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.2/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js
```

/////////////////////////////////////

```
<table id="myTable">
            <tr>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayText("First Name")
                </th>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayText("First Name")
                </th>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayText("Email")
                </th>
                <th>
                </th>
            </tr>
            @foreach (var item in Model)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        @Html.CheckBox("misha", new { onclick = "this.form.submit();" })
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.firstName)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.lastName)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.email)
                    </td>
                </tr>
            }
        </table> 

    <script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function(){
            $('#myTable').dataTable();
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: plz try to give this type of answers in comments section...the user can read the documentation to find how to use datatable.js..